# Python Regular Expression pattern r'(.*[0-9]){5,}'

Tags: python-3.x

I thought the braces require 5 matches.

```
import re

rMatch = re.search(r'(.*[0-9]){5,}', 'A1B2C3D4E5')
print(rMatch)
print(rMatch.groups())
```

Why only one group?
How can I see the 5 matches that are taking place given the use of curly braces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the curly braces state that (.*[0-9]) must be matched 5 times. You can not get the individual matches using curly braces, but you can see a progression. You can also see that if you try 6 matches the search fails.

```
rMatch = re.search(r'(.*[0-9]){1}', 'A1')
print(rMatch)
rMatch = re.search(r'(.*[0-9]){2}', 'A1@2')
print(rMatch)
rMatch = re.search(r'(.*[0-9]){3}', 'A1@2C3')
print(rMatch)
rMatch = re.search(r'(.*[0-9]){4}', 'A1@2C3D4')
print(rMatch)
rMatch = re.search(r'(.*[0-9]){5}', 'A1@2C3D4E5')
print(rMatch)
rMatch = re.search(r'(.*[0-9]){6}', 'A1@2C3D4E5')
print(rMatch)
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='A1'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='A1@2'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='A1@2C3'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='A1@2C3D4'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='A1@2C3D4E5'>
None
```

Answer (score 0):

A more correct pattern would be `(?:[A-Z]+[0-9]+){5,}`:

```py
rMatch = re.search(r'(?:[A-Z]+[0-9]+){5,}', 'A1B2C3D4E5')
if rMatch:
    print("MATCH")
```

If you want to actually *capture* the 5 number alpha matches, then `re.findall` works better:

```py
inp = "A1B2C3D4E5"
matches = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+[0-9]+', inp)
print(matches)  # ['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4', 'E5']
```

Comment: I need to display all the matches found with the braces. I can't use the example without braces.

Comment: Then you should first validate the input string using `re.search`, then capture 5 or more matches using `re.findall`.